# ngx-bootstrap ProgressBar - use of template is depricated

Tags: angular, progress-bar, ngx-bootstrap, ng-template

The latest version of ngx-bootstrap still returns the ProgressBar component using the depricated 'template' element. This gives warnings in the console. But according to the source code in GitHub, the component html uses 'ng-template'. How is this not getting carried over into the latest release? Or is this an ongoing bug?

Regards
JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Angular 4+, use ngx-bootstrap@next - its latest version is 2.0.0-beta.8

Comment: I tried that just now, it still ends up generating the 'template' element within the progressbar.component.js file within node_modules.

Comment: I take it back. Even though the JS doesn't seem to be updated to 'ng-template', the warning is now gone. Many thanks for your help :)